# Cloudflare cf-cache-status DYNAMIC for WebAssembly

Tags: cloudflare

According to the Cloudflare documentation, it is stated that dynamic URLs are not eligible for caching and return 'DYNAMIC' for the 'cf-cache-status'.

```
$ curl -sI https://play.carimbo.cloud/0.0.70/flippingpixels/wiggler/0.0.22/480p/carimbo.wasm | grep cf-cache-status
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
```

Same URL for JavaScript

```
$ curl -sI https://play.carimbo.cloud/0.0.70/flippingpixels/wiggler/0.0.22/480p/carimbo.js | grep cf-cache-status

cf-cache-status: HIT
```

Why is Cloudflare not caching WebAssembly? WebAssembly is considered a web resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a Page Rule

play.carimbo.cloud/*
Cache Level: Cache Everything